# Getting untraceable OSError (exception ignored) after program terminates

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm afraid that I won't be of any help for tracking this down since this issue might come from basically *anywhere* in my code.

The exception occurs after running a Tensorflow training (I don't know if the issue comes from Tensorflow though). I can't see anything broken so I assume this is just an exception that happens somewhere during teardown.

My biggest issue, besides this annoying exception itself, is the fact that I have literally zero information on where it originates from.

```
...
I1123 07:51:21.469002 140168846268160 experiment.py:174] Experiment completed.
Exception ignored in: <function Pool.__del__ at 0x7f7b225304c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in __del__
    self._change_notifier.put(None)
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 378, in put
    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 205, in send_bytes
    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 416, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/speech/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 373, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Is there any way I can get an idea *where* this is happening in my code?

Comment: The traceback looks like you are using multiprocessing. Try running the relevant code in a single unthreaded process to reduce it to a [mre] and probably also get a better traceback.

Comment: This is this type of situation where I cannot simply provide an MVP without seriously digging into the code-base. The question for me is whether or not there could be a  way to get a more meaningful error message. I'm not even talking about the line where the file was opened but why am I not seeing the path for example?

Comment: Probably because the error happened in another process which has already been terminated.

Comment: Maybe it's a Tensorflow issue then because I didn't start another process.

Comment: The traceback clearly shows `multiprocessing` in the call tree. Perhaps look for a code path which doesn't use that.